# Hostapd - detect and execute command when a device is connected - error

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, raspbian, hostapd

I am trying to execute a command on hostapd when there is a new connection established.

I used this example:

[hostapd: execute a command when there is new connection established](https://superuser.com/questions/1071354/hostapd-execute-a-command-when-there-is-new-connection-established?r=SearchResults)

But when I start the script, on device connection, I receive an error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hostapd_cli -a '/onHostapdChange.sh'
Selected interface 'wlan0'

execv: No such file or directory
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: Does `/onHostapdChange.sh` actually exist?

Comment: Make sure the interpreter at the beginning of your script exists. E.g. (#!/bin/sh)

Comment: What are the parameters to the command? When I tried this `hostapd_cli` didn't exit. Do you have to re-do this ever time the machine restarts or does it somehow remember to run the script?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like, there is no such file at the specified path:

```
/onHostapdChange.sh
```

I would suggest you try to put the full path of the shell script inside the argument.